# access 2010 command button to follow a hyperlink in a list box

Tags: hyperlink, combobox, listbox, ms-access-2010, commandbutton

I am wandering if you can get a command button to follow a hyperlink in a list box or even a combo box.

I have looked high and low and cant find any way to do this, so I'm hoping that someone out there can show me the light!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
Dim Url As String

Url = Me!YourListBox.Value
Application.FollowHyperlink Url
```